# Any C lib for stateful inspection of network sessions?

Tags: c, networking, state-machine

Is there any C/C++ lib(of course Open-sourced) for developing applications of stateful inspection on network session, for instance, following the FTP session state?

I know there is a pre-processor module in Snort namely stream4. But an independent lib is more flexible for us which implemented in C is preferred.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your target platform? I imagine it'll be much easier to find a solution in Linux/*nix-based than Windows

Comment: My target platform is Linux with SMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how applicable this will be to whatever you're doing, but you could try to extract the [Linux NAT connection tracking code](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.39/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_ftp.c) and adapting it to your needs. It's not a nice pre-made library, but it's a start.

Comment: My use case is to perform stateful inspection over 10Gbps network. Ftp is just one protocol we are interested in.

Comment: @deepsky, yes, Linux has a number of conntrack plugins other than just FTP, if you implement the proper interfaces. Or you could do your inspection as a kernel module